# How can I sync two sliders with mousewheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am using Swiper slider on my page. And on my page i have two sliders. I want, when i use scroll up - first slider go up and second slider go down. And when i use scroll down - first slider go down and second slider go up.

I write this

https://288757.playcode.io
https://playcode.io/288757?tabs=style.css&output
but this code is not good, becouse work strange on mac and doesn't work on firefox and becouse i down't use mousewheel swiper parametr.

```
        $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event){
            var width = $(document).width();

            if(width >= 769){
                if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                    mySwiper1.slideNext(600);
                    mySwiper2.slidePrev(600);
                }
                else {
                    mySwiper1.slidePrev(600);
                    mySwiper2.slideNext(600);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is my sliders without this code
https://jsfiddle.net/gpkd83nr/2/

How can I sync two sliders with mousewheel? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this ?

```
window.onwheel=function(e){
            var val=e.deltaY;
        if(val>0){
         mySwiper1.slideNext(600);
         mySwiper2.slidePrev(600);
             }
        else{
           mySwiper1.slidePrev(600);
           mySwiper2.slideNext(600);
        }
    }
```